# Spring Security environment specific intercept-url

Tags: spring, spring-security

Here is the Spring Security `intercept-url` configuration:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**.html"
                       access="ROLE_USER" requires-channel="https" />
```

I want to make `requires-channel="any"` for local environment.
Is it possible to add absolute URL in the pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Spring *bean definition profiles* to achieve that.

```
<beans profile="local">

</beans>
```

It's a new feature. Take a look at the entry in Spring Source blog: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/